I have disabled anonymous access for storage account and while creating the module in automation I am getting below error
I have disabled anonymous access for storage account and while creating the module in automation I am getting below error PublicAccessNotPermitted
Here is the code
I need to disable anonymous access for storage account but module will create

Your post says here is the code but there is no code. Please edit and add the code segment. Also, it would be helpful if you clarified your question. Also, please clarify the last sentence in your post. It's not clear what you're trying to communicate.
